# Добавить элементу класс если имеет вложенный label

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jade

Есть задача, нужно добавиться элементу `div` класс `has-error`, если `div` имеет вложенный `label`.
 Нужно сделать так, что когда проходит проверку на ошибку, поле inputa подсвечивается класом has-error diva.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var labels = $("div > label");
        for(var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++){
            labels[i].addClass('has-error')
        }
    })
form(action="/registerme" method="POST")
                .form-group
                    label(for="name") Ваше имя
                    div.forError
                        input(type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Name")
                        if errors
                            each error in errors
                                if error.param === 'username'
                                    div.has-error
                                        label.control-label
                                            i(class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true")
                                                | &nbsp; #{error.msg}
                .form-group
                    label(for="rEmail") Ваш Email
                    div.forError
                        input(type="email" class="form-control" id="rEmail" placeholder="Email" name="useremail")
                        if errors
                            each error in errors
                                if error.param === 'useremail'
                                    div.has-error
                                        label.control-label
                                            i(class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true")
                                                | &nbsp; #{error.msg}
                .form-group
                    label(for="rPassword") Пароль
                    div.forError
                        input(type="password" class="form-control" id="rPassword" placeholder="Password" name="userpassword")
                        if errors
                            each error in errors
                                if error.param === 'userpassword'
                                    div.has-error
                                        label.control-label
                                            i(class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true")
                                                | &nbsp; #{error.msg}
                .form-group
                    label(for="сPassword") Повторите пароль
                    div.forError
                        input(type="password" class="form-control" id="сPassword" placeholder="Password" name="confirmpassword")
                        if errors
                            each error in errors
                                if error.param === 'confirmpassword'
                                    div.has-error
                                        label.control-label
                                            i(class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true")
                                                | &nbsp; #{error.msg}
                button(type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block")
                    i(class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true")
                    | &nbsp; Зарегистрироваться
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div").each(function(i, div) {
    var cache = $(div);
    if (cache.find("> label").length > 0) {
      cache.addClass('has-error')
    }
  });
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
div.has-error {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label></label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <form>
      <label></label>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div><strong></strong>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но код добавляет класс has-error всем div'ам, а не тому у кого есть label

Comment: В моем примере добавляет только тем, у которых есть есть label. Воспользуйтесь запуском примера, чтобы убедиться в этом.

Answer (score 1):

Например применить `has()`:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var div = $("div"); 
  
 div.has('label').addClass('has-error');

});
```

```css
.has-error {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

<div>
  Просто блок
</div>

<div>Блок с <label>label</label></div>
```

Для Вашего примера тоже работает:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var div = $("div"); 
  
 div.has('label').addClass('has-error');

});
```

```css
.has-error input{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form action="/registerme" method="POST">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name">Ваше имя</label>
    <div class="forError">
      <input type="text" id="name" name="username" placeholder="Name" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rEmail">Ваш Email</label>
    <div class="forError">
      <input type="email" id="rEmail" placeholder="Email" name="useremail" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="rPassword">Пароль</label>
    <div class="forError">
      <input type="password" id="rPassword" placeholder="Password" name="userpassword" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="сPassword">Повторите пароль</label>
    <div class="forError">
      <input type="password" id="сPassword" placeholder="Password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  
    <div class="form-group">
    ТУТ НЕТ LABEL
    <div class="forError">
      <input type="password" id="сPassword" placeholder="Password" name="confirmpassword" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-check"></i>&nbsp; Зарегистрироваться</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Нужно добавить класс к div, а не к label.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, проблема не решилась, класс has-error добавляется всем дивам

Comment: @ДимаОпря, как это всем? У меня же в примере как раз для блока с `label` и без!

Comment: @ДимаОпря, приведите тогда свой html!

Comment: @ДимаОпря, все работает! Просто у Вас во всех блоках `form-group` присутствует тег `label`